# Workflow to trigger email notification when new document is added/edited not sending email

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, email

I am new to SharePoint, especially SharePoint 2013.

I have created a workflow via SharePoint Designer 2013 with the following conditions- If a new document is created with the "Date Created" equaling today, an email notification will be sent out.

If says "Completed" in the workflow taskbar but no email is ever sent nor is there any history within the workflow history.

Does anyone know that might be wrong?

I have been able to created other workflows and have email notifications in the past and today.

Thanks in advance!

---

If statement in SP Designer:

### [image: If statement in SP Designer]

Workflow settings- to start automatically when new document is created/modified:

### [image: Workflow settings- to start automatically when new document is created/modified]

Column showing completed but no workflow history or email:

[image: Column showing completed but no workflow history or email]

Answer (score 2):

Date Created returns date and time, but Today returns only date (12:00 AM). So they are not equal, and your condition is never true.  -- Evgenii Vilkov

It's true, so use the below action during comparison.
Change compare action **equal** to **equals(ignoring time)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Date Created` returns date and time, but `Today` returns only date (12:00 AM). So they are not equal, and your condition is never true. You can check this by logging these values into history list (there is a special action for this).

I'm not sure this solution fits you, but you can change `equals` condition to `equals (ignoring time)`, then workflow should work.